# Clang-Format: How to specify a custom format options file?

Tags: clang-format

I'm trying to configure a custom style options file for clang-format v6.0.0 running on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.  I started out by generating an options file based upon the llvm style using the following command line, which worked fine:

```
clang-format -style=llvm -dump-config > .clang-format
```

The documentation for clang-format states the following:
"When the desired code formatting style is different from the available options, the style can be customized using the -style="{key: value, ...}" option or by putting your style configuration in the .clang-format or _clang-format file in your project’s directory and using clang-format -style=file."

So just as a test I used the unchanged .clang-format file I generated above and used the following command line:

```
clang-format -style=.clang-format Test.c
```

The result was a message that said

```
"Invalid value for -style"
```

I then changed the name of .clang-format to _clang-format and tried it again but the result was the same.  So, my question is, "How do I specify a specific style options file?"

Comment: My mistake.   -style=file means use the actual word file, not substitute the name of the desired file.  I overlooked that there were no angle brackets around file: <file>

Comment: The page where the clang-format documentation states this is https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you correctly discovered command is expecting the literal `-style=file`. For example `clang-format.exe -i -style=file` The `-i` option is to execute the changes in place. The `-style=file` is telling the program to look in the current directory for the configuration file named `.clang-format or _clang-format` [Configuration options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html). If the config file is still not found the program will move up a directory and continue searching and so on. More command line documentation can be found [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html).